# NullPointerException when uploading file using Struts 2

Tags: tomcat, file-upload, struts

This is JSP

```
<s:form action="uploadfile.action" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST"  cssClass="bodyClass">
    <tr>
        <td>
            Image:
        </td>
        <td style="width: 200px;">
            <s:file id='image' name='uploadedfile' cssClass="formTextField"  />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="submit" value="Upload" class="button"/>
        </td>
    </tr>

</s:form>
```

This is Struts .xml

```
 <package name="upload" namespace="/upload" extends="struts-default">
            <action name="uploadfile" class="com.secureweb.web.upload.UploadAction">
                <result name="uploadImage">/pages/fileupload/uploadimage.jsp</result>
            </action>
    </package>
```

Action class

```
public class UploadAction extends ActionSupport {
    private File uploadedfile;

    public String execute() throws Exception {
        try {
           System.out.println(uploadedfile.getName());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        return "uploadImage";
    }

    public File getUploadedfile() {
        return uploadedfile;
    }

    public void setUploadedfile(File uploadedfile) {
        this.uploadedfile = uploadedfile;
    }
}
```

Libraries in my project

```
 commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar
    commons-lang-2.3.jar
    displaytag-1.2.jar
    displaytag-export-poi-1.2.jar
    displaytag-portlet-1.2.jar
    log4j-1.2.14.jar
    pljava.jar
    postgresql-8.3-603.jdbc4.jar
    postgresql-8.3-604.jdbc3.jar
    cos.jar

    Struts 2 2.1.8 Basic- commons-io-1.3.2.jar
                          commons-fileupload-1.2.1.jar
                          commons-logging-1.0.4.jar
                          freemarker-2.3.15.jar
                          ognl-2.7.3.jar
                          struts2-core-2.1.8.1.jar
                          xwork-core-2.1.6.jar
    Then there is persistance.jar of EJB
    And there is also Hibernate Library.
```

No other

Result is NullPointerException because attribute uploadedfile is null. File uploading is not working correctly. Why that variable is getting always value null. My OS is Ubuntu Linux 11.4, Web Server - Apache Tomcat 6. IDE- Netbeans.

Answer (score 0):

Probably because Struts 2 already implements complete file uploading capabilities without having to do all the work manually.

Please see the [file upload docs](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/file-upload.html) and use what the framework already gives you.

Here are some additional issues:

- Unless you've set the default theme to `"simple"`, the HTML generated by the form will be invalid; the default theme emits the form input elements inside table rows/cells.
- The `"action"` attribute of the `<s:form>` tag should be the name of the action *without* the `.action` suffix.

With those issues fixed, your code works as-is. Have you modified the default interceptor stack?

Comment: I tried with setter and getter method to access the file, but it didn't work. still I am getting null value for file attribute. I already tried it and end without result, For ensuring that I once again tried, still the result is null :)

Comment: @MohammedSwafvan Please update your question with the code and config used with the built-in mechanism, along with the libraries you're deploying.

Comment: @MohammedSwafvan You get the NPE where, when you try to print the name? Any startup errors in the log? What libraries are you deploying?

Comment: @MohammedSwafvan How do you show the initial form? In other words if you just go to `/upload/upload.action`, you'll see the form, but there won't be any files uploaded because you haven't submitted the form.

Comment: Actually the execution is entering in action class on debug, but value for file is null, I am getting other parameters in the same form, if given. And my Action name is uploadfile.action, upload is pakage name. Anyway I changed my action to uploadfile. Still the problem exist. I didn't changed default stack, I don't know what it is.

Comment: @MohammedSwafvan The `action` attribute in the form should not include the `.action` extension. I cannot reproduce the issue you're having. Is the code you posted an exact cut-and-paste? Please describe the exact steps you're taking to display the form, fill it out, and submit it.

Comment: Is there any OS security related issues?. that is my doubt

Comment: My requirement is, I have to display an image in user's screen. user select an image, then submit it to server. Then I will take it out and display in user's page, like the insert image button of Gmail's editor. but here the very first step is getting failed.

Comment: @MohammedSwafvan I'm not interested in the requirement, I want to know the precise steps you're taking to upload the file, from the initial form display through the form submission.

Comment: Dave, In my webpage I have a insert image button on clicking it, I insert an Iframe to the webpage using javascript, with source as the page url. So the page for browsing the image is displaying in Iframe. When I click the upload button it will go to the above action class., where I am getting null value for file attribute.

Comment: @MohammedSwafvan How do you display the JSP? Directly, or through an action? In any case, I can't reproduce the issue. Create a minimal failing example, put the project and its POM file on github, and I'll take a look.

Comment: It is a big project actually :(

Comment: @MohammedSwafvan Which is why I asked for a minimal failing example.

Comment: I will try later. need some setup.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you add the FileUpload Interceptor to the interceptor stack of your action. You may refer the documents below to know how to:

http://struts.apache.org/2.0.6/docs/file-upload-interceptor.html

http://struts.apache.org/2.0.14/docs/file-upload.html

http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-file-upload-example/

I recently worked on a project with fileupload on Tomcat 6.0, Firefox & Chrome using FileUpload interceptor with restrictions on NetBeans 6.9 and things were fine. Please keep updating your result.